# Integral closed domain and localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ respect to prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

We know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is integrally closed domain. This means that with respect to its prime ideal $p$, localization $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is also integrally closed in its field of fractions.

Suppose that we pick $p$ as generated by $2$. Then, $1/3$ will be in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Now $2/6$ is not in $\mathbb{Z}_p$; however, in $\mathbb{Q}$, $1/3=2/6$. But $2/6$ is indeed in the field of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, which is also $\mathbb{Q}$.

So $2/6$ is the solution of every monic polynomial equation (equalling zero) that has $1/3$ as the solution. This seems to go in conflict with the definition of integral closedness.

Where did I go wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You are confused about fractions:  $2/6$ is *equal* to $1/3$, and so lies in $\mathbb Z_2$.